# The characteristic function of the random time $N$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

The rv's $X_1,X_2,X_3,\ldots,X_n$ are I.I.D and have the following pmf's:

$$p_x(-1)=1/4\quad p_x(0) = 1/2,\quad p_x(1) = 1/4$$

The random time $N$ is defined as:

$$N = \min\{n \mid X_n = 0\}$$

Show that $N\in Fs(1/2)$ with the use of the characteristic function.

I've tried to solve it but failed miserably....the problem is that we have never solved anything quite like this in class, calculating the C.F of a random variable that is an index of another random variable.

Comment: Can you compute P(N=n) for every n?

Comment: I don't really see how you would be able to do that with the information given...

Comment: Just follow: first, what is the event [N=1] and what is P(N=1)?

Comment: The event N = 1 results in $X_1$ being 0 and the probability of of said rv being zero is 1/2..

Comment: Excellent, thus you know P(N=1). Now, what is the event [N=2] and what is P(N=2)?

Comment: So P(N=n) = 1/2 for every n I assume?

Comment: No no no, go more slowly: what is the event [N=2]? Can you express it in terms of X1, X2, X3, etc.?

Comment: Well if N = n implies that $X_n$ equals zero then then that should equate to: P(N=n)=P($X_n$=0)?

Comment: [N=2] is not [X2=0]. On [X1=X2=0], N=1, not N=2. So, [N=2] is...

Comment: X3 upwards to Xn are not involved in [N=2]. So, what is [N=2] in terms of X1, X2. Yes X2=0 is necessary to achieve N=2 but it is not enough, actually [N=2]=...

Comment: ((Comments by the OP now deleted.))

Comment: I apologize if I'm slow to understand but if I'm to think logically about N then N represents the index of the first variable $X$ that becomes equal to zero. Thus N=2 means that $X_2$ is zero which also should imply that $X_1$ is non zero, because if $X_1$ would be zero it would just equate N=1 just the way you stated above?

Comment: Yes, if X1=0 then N=2 is impossible. Sooo... in the end, [N=2] is...

Comment: N=2 should equate to:

[N=2] = [$X_1$ $\neq$ 0, $X_2$ = 0]?

Comment: **Yes!** Hence P(N=2) is... Next, write [N=3] similarly and deduce P(N=3), and finally all these should suggest a generalization to P(N=n) for every n.

Comment: So if I use the same logic then P(N=2) = P($X_1 \neq 0,X_2=0$) and because the RV's are I.I.D then that should equate to:

$P(X_1 \neq 0,X_2=0) = P(X_1 \neq 0)P(X_2 = 0)$ and just do the same for N=3 and upwards like you implied..I'll try and see what happens!

Comment: Exactly. (When you will have a full solution (which should be soon now), you may post it as an answer and even, later on, accept it.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C.F of N is the following:

$\varphi_N = E[e^{itN}]=\sum_{k=1}^ne^{itk}P(N=k)$

Where $P(N=k)=pq^{k-1}$.

Which can be deduced from taking P(N=1), P(N=2), P(N=3) and so on in the following manner:

$P(N=1)= P(X_1=0) = \frac{1}{2}$

$P(N=2)= P(X_1\neq 0,X_2=0) = P(X_1 \neq 0)P(X_2=0)= \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}$

$P(N=3)= P(X_1\neq 0,X_2 \neq 0,X_3 = 0) = P(X_1 \neq 0)P(X_2 \neq 0)P(X_3=0)= \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}$

And if one keeps on going one should be able to see that all this equates to:

$P(N=k)=(1-P(X_k =0))^{k-1}P(X_k=0)=pq^{k-1}$

where  $q=(1-P(X_k=0))$ and $p=\frac{1}{2}$

This then gives:

$\varphi_N = E[e^{itN}]=\sum_{k=1}^ne^{itk}pq^{k-1}$, which equals to the C.F of the Fs(1/2):

$\varphi_{Fs(1/2)} =\frac{\frac{1}{2}e^{it}}{1-\frac{1}{2}e^{it}}$

Also I want to thank Did for the help and patience.